# How do I know which access-control-allow-headers to allow for CORS?

Tags: http-headers, cors

Given these request headers:

```
Host: api.example.org
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:41.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/41.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
DNT: 1
Origin: https://web.example.org
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

And these response headers:

```
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Date: Tue, 13 Oct 2015 10:57:34 GMT
Server: nginx/1.8.0
access-control-allow-headers: Authorization, Content-Type
access-control-allow-methods: PUT, DELETE, PATCH
access-control-allow-origin: *
```

This works even though only the `Authorization` and `Content-Type` headers are explicitly allowed. Why didn't I have to allow other headers that my browser sends? (like `DNT` for example)

---

**Update**: [this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CORS-safelisted_request_header) contains an overview of simple headers (default CORS-safelisted request headers):

> A simple header (or CORS-safelisted request header) is one of the
> following HTTP headers:
>
> - Accept
> - Accept-Language
> - Content-Language
> - Content-Type with a MIME type of its parsed value (ignoring parameters) of either application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, or text/plain.
>
> Or one of these client hint headers:
>
> - DPR
> - Downlink
> - Save-Data
> - Viewport-Width
> - Width

Comment: You haven't listed the the actual HTTP verb but the request looks like a preflight request. Do you have a line that looks like `if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {` in your nginx config? More info on CORS preflight here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests

Comment: As mentioned by @morloch, in preflight request you are asking for the permission to send particular headers. So until you perform the actual operation, you would not know whether they were accepted or not. There is also a set of headers that are explicitly allowed (http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#simple-header).

Comment: @MirecMiskuf does this mean I don't have to allow the header Accept-Language on the server as it is allowed by default through CORS?

Comment: @adiii4 - that seems to be the case, as per the spec.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without seeing your code to generate the headers, or on which system you are serving from, i.e. nginx or apache, the best I can do is refer you to http://client.cors-api.appspot.com/client which will allow you to test your CORS requests.  Also, you should look at http://enable-cors.org/server.html for your specific setup.  For instance on nginx, you could have something like this

```
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
```

There is a set of normal headers, and then the set of headers that you have to explicitly call out. see http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/#toc-adding-cors-support-to-the-server about setting it up on a server.

Answer (score 0):

The `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` is attached by backend, you cannot control that header on client side.`Access-Control-Allow-Headers` should be returned in response object.

So to include other headers into `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` header in response object - you have to configure your web server or update backend application which serves requests to attach desired value of `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` to each request.

To allow any headers in your client requests server should add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header to each response.

There are a lot of articles and info of how you can setup CORS to work in the way you want. For example that one - [Enabling CORS](http://enable-cors.org/server.html)